# document.cookie cannot be referenced in the chrome extension sandbox

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sandbox, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Imported at https://apis.google.com/js/client.js in the sandbox to create an MV3 extension that works with Google Sheets.
However, I got an error because it is getting document.cookie.
The following question is based on MCVE of the above.

The following error occurs when document.cookie is referenced in the sandbox of the chrome extension.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.
> at chrome-extension://dmjmafjcmjmkimijfodamlckfkikakjk/sandbox.html:4:26

Please tell me how to solve it.

Defining allow-same-origin in manifest.json fails to load manifest.json.

Setting sandbox="allow-same-origin" in the iframe tag will result in the following error.

> Blocked script execution in 'chrome-extension://dmjmafjcmjmkimijfodamlckfkikakjk/sandbox.html' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

Setting sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" in the iframe tag will result in the following error.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.
> at chrome-extension://dmjmafjcmjmkimijfodamlckfkikakjk/sandbox.html:4:26

manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": [
      "sandbox.html"
    ]
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <iframe src="sandbox.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

sandbox.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    console.log(document.cookie);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @wOxxOm, Because this is an MCVE and the original purpose is to allow external JS to get the document.cookie.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I totally agree with your opinion, but I need it for https://apis.google.com/js/client.js to work in sandbox.

Comment: Try faking it via Object.defineProperty(document, 'cookie', {set: ..., get: ...})